# list directories and allow user to select directory name as option

Tags: bash

I am working on what is really my first ever bash script. I would like to have in each step of this current script give a numbered list that the user can select a number and then have that directory name saved as the variable rather than having to manually type the directory name. I am not looking to have it done for me (although i wont turn it down) but a nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo source directory you would like me to copy from?
read srcDir

echo destination directory you would like to copy to?
read destDir

rsync -avh /home/tendesig/public_html/respond/app/sites/$srcDir/. /home/$destDir/public_html/.
chown -R $destDir:$destDir /home/$destDir/public_html
```

Comment: You are looking at `select`. The syntax is `select var in list; do commands; done`. `list` being an array of directories. `commands` should contain actions taken to verify `$REPLY` which contains the numeric response and `$var` will contain the corresponding directory.

Comment: Look at the [select](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select) builtin.

Comment: A good search term would be [[bash] select do done](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bash]+select+do+done)